Should I follow my processor manual or system motherboard specified max RAM?
I use an Asus X42JY model laptop with a Intel Pentium Processor P6200.
I want to upgrade my RAM from 4GB to 8GB, but the system motherboard manual specified that for this particular model, the max supported RAM is 4GB of DDR3 RAM, but when I checked the Intel Processor manual it mentioned that for the "Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type)" it will be 8GB.
So can I actually upgrade my RAM to 8GB? I do use a 64 bit machine currently.
Edit:
So I inserted 2 pairs of 4GB of RAM, and it succeeded. I did use dual rank RAM tho, if that matters.

Its a 'non answer' but there's two elements here - the total support of 8gb might be 2 slots of 4 gb, but only one exists physically - so per slot capacity, as well as number of slots could matter.

IMHO think about this: processor support 8GB, but if chipset/motherboard do not support 8GB, your system will recognise 4GB

Can you edit the question to include a link to the system motherboard manual, as I wasn't able to find it on the ASUS site. Also, how many SODIMM memory slots does the ASUS X42JY laptop have?

@ChesterGillon - It’s up to the author to do that.

"the max supported RAM is 4GB of DDR3 RAM" Be careful if you buy more RAM, it will probably require a SODIMM (Small Outline Dual In-line Memory Module) stick, it's smaller than a regular DDR3 stick.

I suspect the answer's a little more complicated than it seems at first glance.
Its entirely possible that the system comes with a BIOS or chipset restriction that prevents more than 4 GB from being installed. However, there seem to be examples of the same model (with a different processor) with 8 GB installed, so it seems unlikely that it's locked down.
These laptops appear to have come with Windows 7 (32-bit) out of the box, and the OS wouldn't support more than 4 GB of RAM. Upgrading to a 64-bit OS would be necessary to take full advantage of more RAM.
They also seem to have 2 RAM slots as per the ifixit teardown, and 4 GB was a common DDR3 size. A pair of 4 GB sticks should work.
I can't be sure (ASUS doesn't even have a manual for this model from what I can find, or a QVL) but I'd say there's a decent chance it would work.

To add to this answer: this was surprisingly hard-to-find information, but it seems that the P6200 is indeed a 64-bit processor, so upgrading to a 64-bit OS would be possible.

Anything after a core 2 duo was so I kind of took it for granted. There's exceptions come to think of it

Actually, now that I think of it, the fact that its manual (according to the asker) says it supports up to 8 GB of RAM would imply that it's a 64-bit processor anyway.

It added an extra level of indirection, but there was an entire extended memory model for the 32-bit Intel CPUs called Physical Address Extension. As early as the Pentium Pro (and Windows 2000) they were technically capable of 36-bit addressing! I think an individual process was still limited to 4GB of address space.

@ElliottFrisch: The "extra level of indirection" is only on TLB miss, an extra level of page tables.  (Which the page-walker hardware can typically cache so so TLB-miss cost doesn't even go up as much as you might think.)  And yes, virtual addresses are still 32-bit so per-process is still 4 GiB.  Actually 3GiB with the OS reserving some of that, unless you use a 64-bit OS.  Linus Torvalds explains why PAE sucked so much of OS developers with one of his classic rants (packed with good technical info): https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/

@Hearth Intel® Pentium® Processor P6200 on the Intel site says the processor does support a
64-bit instruction set.

@PeterCordes 32 bit windows uses 2 GB for userland programs and 2 GB for the kernel. You can boot windows in a mode allowing 3 GB for a program (this requires restrictin the memory addresses on the kernel for all programs), but can only be taken advantage of by programs explicitly compiled with a switch stating they support that mode (a linker switch, actually. It's a flag in the PE header), otherwise they are restricted to 2 GB as well even if the OS was booted in 3GB/1 GB mode. Of course, this limit only applies to memory use by a single program. > 4GB can be used by sum of several exes.

The "safe" thing to do is to follow the motherboard manual as this is what ultimately limits the memory.
That said, very often the manuals are incomplete and you can add more RAM then stated.
(I typically look at the Crucial and/or Kingston memory configuration site for my system and defer to that for the exact memory to buy - It does not let me down, but if it did at least I would have recourse to get a refund on the memory if it doesn't work. Unfortunately I could not find a reference to your board on these systems)

You may be able to go even above your manual's specifications:
Last month, I upgraded an (admittedly much more recent) Lenovo Ideapad 330S-15ARR laptop running Windows 10.
The manual seems to state a maximum of 8GiB (it came with 4GiB soldered to the MB, and 4GiB in a slot).
However, this could be simply the maximum they ever planned to sell it with.
Even asking Windows (wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices) reported a maximum of 16GiB in 2 slots, which some suggest would also mean a max of 8GiB per slot.
However, I bought the largest ddr4 so-dimm I could get - 32GiB - and am now enjoying 36GiB (4+32) fully recognized in Windows.
So far no glitches after a month or so of use, and a quick test indicated that I can indeed allocate 34G+ of memory.
Sure, I may well have lost the advantage of dual channel, but it's still way preferable to swapping!
If you can return the memory if it doesn't work or isn't fully recognized (even if opened - check with the vendor!), or maybe go to a physical PC store/repairman to test before buying, you may be able to use even more ram than it seems from the manuals.
A repairman might even have good second-hand chips for cheap, although possibly not the largest sizes.

I assume your proccessor supports 32GB (or above) ?

Clearly, since it works.
It's an AMD Ryzen 5 2500U.
From what I can tell, both mine and yours have a Physical Address Extension (PAE) width of 36 bits. This should allow the processor (only) to address up to 64 GB of physical memory.

There can be real limitations posed by the motherboard that go beyond those posed by the CPU. Generally falling into two main categories.

On older chips, the memory controller was on the chipset not the CPU, so the motherboard chipset could limit max ram. Your processor is new enough that the memory controller is on the CPU though.
As well as total memory limits, memory controllers often have limits on the size of chips they can talk to. So if the board has less memory slots than the CPU supports then this can limit total memory.

But it's also true that laptop manufacturers frequently understate the max memory of their systems. I have three laptops of various ages fitted with more ram than the manufacturer said they supported. Two of them are succesfully using all that ram, one (the oldest) is successfully using more than the manufacturer states but less than the total ram fitted because it's chipset has a 4GB address space limitation.
So you can try 2x4GB, if it works great, if it doesn't work you can't really complain.
If you do try 2x4GB I would recommend dual-rank modules rather than single rank. These will use a size of memory chip that existed at the time the machine was designed. When I tried a 4GB single rank module in a machine of that era the machine was unstable, while a dual-rank module was fine.


I use an Asus X42JY model laptop with a Intel Pentium Processor P6200.

Cool, what's the motherboard model number?


but the system motherboard manual specified that for this particular model

Cool, what's the motherboard model number?


So can I actually upgrade my RAM to 8GB?

Possibly yes, you have not shared the motherboard model number.

2 x 4GB DDR3 sodimm sticks average $10-$20. This seems like a trivial cost for potentially big benefit.

My motherboard version is "K42JY" if you are interested.

@CPP_is_no_STANDARD That seems to be your laptop model, bud. What's the motherboard brand and model? Download and run CPU-z to learn and share this info.

Not sure why but when I run CPU-Z my whole computer crashes.

@CPP_is_no_STANDARD Well that's a new one for me. Can you get the model number from the BIOS or anything? There are other programs besides CPU-z which will reveal the motherboard model; I don't recall which off the top of my head though.

Motherboard brand?AsusTek Computer Inc.
